# monitoring results in spark Pagerank execution

Tags: scala, apache-spark, monitoring, pagerank

I have ran the pageRank example of spark on scala IDE. I want to keep the history of the job execution even the execution have finished. 
Is there any tool which help me to visualize the results graphically, to have track those metrics : amount of memory, I/O disc, time execution, CPU, ...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a monitoring rest-api

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api

and here is how to use it

http://techblog.kenshoo.com/2015/11/spark-monitoring-tips-from-trenches.html